# Chrome on Android finds colors from sites and uses them for action bar. How to achieve this using WebView in Android using Java?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

[image: chrome finds site colors]

As you can see in the picture, Chrome browser of Android finds colors from site(here blue color for example) and uses them for action bar(blue color for action bar) and for text color of EditText(white color) which is present in action bar. I want to achieve similar using WebView in Android using Java. How to achieve this?

Comment: Hmmm... you could try grabbing a screenshot from the `WebView` and hand that to a `Palette`.

Comment: I tried this approach but detected colors are not that much perfect.

Comment: Well, Chrome is basically controlling the "inside" of the `WebView`, so it is going to have more options and power than will apps like yours that only work with the "outside" of the `WebView`. And, we do not know what algorithm Chrome is using for selecting the color. If you are expecting to match Chrome, you may be disappointed.

Comment: Yes. But I think this needs to be discovered in future because this whole thing is cool.